# posts comments goes to trash

Tags: plugins, posts, themes, comments, trash

My website was working fine until today, I just discovered that all comments made goes straight to trash.

I did not install new plugins, I don't have akismet. It just started. I have deactivated all my plugins and yet the issue persists. I don't know what the issue is.

Is there any code I need to add to my functions.php file to make this stop ?

Comment: Please see these issues may be these can help : https://ask.shoutmeloud.com/t/comments-are-going-in-trash/30592 and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/comments-going-straight-to-trash/

Comment: That did not help my issue. If it's a database issue, I don't even know. Those links did not help matters

Comment: Do you have anything set in Settings / Discussion / Comment Blacklist?

Comment: No I do not have anything in the comment blacklist. It's completely empty